# MingW glfw3 skipping incompatible libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32

Tags: c++, gcc, glfw, mingw-w64

I'm working on Opengl with MingW and I was testing this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// OpenGL
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Window, Keyboard Manager lib
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// for 3D Calculation
#include <GLM/glm.hpp>

using namespace glm;

int main()
{

  if (!glfwInit())
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to initializing GLFW!");
    return -1;
  }

  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


  GLFWwindow *window;
  window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);

  if (window == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to OpenGLFW window");
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
  }

  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  glewExperimental = true;
  if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to initialize GLEW");
    return -1;
  }
}
```

this code have to show black screen and closed right away. but when i compile this code. error log is showing.

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\msys64\mingw64\lib/libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0x2db): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0x8bb): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xa0b): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xdda): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xde9): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceGammaRamp'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xdf2): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xf67): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xf76): undefined reference to `__imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text+0xf7f): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x21a): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDIBSection'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x253): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateBitmap'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x30e): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x3a7): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x43c): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateRectRgn'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):(.text+0x477): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0x182): undefined reference to `__imp_SwapBuffers'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0x42d): undefined reference to `__imp_ChoosePixelFormat'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0x43b): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0xc90): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0xe7a): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0xe94): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):(.text+0x1490): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'
```

and this is a build cli

```
g++.exe -IC:\msys64\mingw64\include -LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib -lfreeglut -lglew32 -lglu32 -lgdi32 -lglfw3 -lopengl32 D:\Privrate\Project\OpenGL\tutorial_1.cpp C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\*.a -o D:\Privrate\Project\OpenGL\build\tutorial_1.exe
```

i think the problem is the library, `libgdi32.a`. but everytime i compile this message is showing.

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\msys64\mingw64\lib/libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
```

i find out what `skipping incompatible...` the problem is that it's 32bit library. but i have to use 64bit for the program. is there a any solution?

Comment: Why is a 32bit library file in your `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib` folder? I'm pretty sure only 64bit libraries should be in there.

Comment: but `skipping incompatible...` error only show when i call 32-bit library.

Comment: Also, why did you add all lib-files like this: `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\*.a`, that's just weird.

Comment: then how do i have to write compile cli?

Comment: Make sure to put the `-l` flags after the sources that depend on them. Also make sure you use `gcc` from the same location as where you use the libraries from in case of system libraries like `libgdi32.a`